# Not able to change mouseDrag option after initialization without destroying the instance (owlCarousel 2)

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel-2

I'm using OwlCarousel v2.1.6
I want to enable/disable an option based on some user interaction. To be more specific I want to enable disable the mouseDrag functionality.
I tried the solutions purposed on other similar questions but none is working.

I've created a jsFiddle where there are some of my tries. If anyone is able to solve that would be appreciated, Maybe I'm just missing something obvious.

https://jsfiddle.net/ny9vrLq7/

code below

```html
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();


  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("timeout ran!");

    // this doesn't work (throws exception)
    /*$('.owl-carousel').trigger('change.owl.carousel', {
        mouseDrag: false
    });*/

    // this does nothing
    /*$('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel').options.mouseDrag = false;
        $('.owl-carousel').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');*/

    // this does nothing
    /*$('.owl-carousel').trigger('change', { property: { name: 'mouseDrag', value: false } });*/

    // this does nothing
    /*$('.owl-carousel').trigger('changeOption.owl.carousel', {
        mouseDrag: false
        });*/

    // this does nothing
    /*var owl = $(".owl-carousel");
    var carousel = owl.data('owl.carousel');
    carousel.settings.mouseDrag = false;
    carousel.options.mouseDrag = false;
    owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');*/

  }, 2500);
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel div {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 300x;
  height: 300px;
}
.owl-dots {
  display:none;
}
```

I cannot destroy the owlCarousel instance because of how other part of the software are written.

I'm trying with Chrome v75 (desktop)
owlCarousel v2.1.6 (I've tried also with the latest version and still i'm not able to make it work)

Comment: No, on desktop, sorry for not specifiying, I've updated the question.

Comment: no worries, thank you!